# Best way to implement an expiring link, httpwebresponse.expired?

Tags: vb.net, httpwebresponse

I must be using bad search terms because this has got to be a super-simple question, but I'm not getting any meaningful search hits.  I am sending out a link to a page that will expire.  MY script checks whether the link is still valid.  when valid I have no problems, but when invalid I can't find a simple response and instead I keep stopping myself from writing a hundred lines of code.

I would like to put a simple response.error in the sub Page_Load().
response.error("expired")? something like that? I could do a response.redirect but that would mean a new error handler page.  isn't there something super simple?  I don't want any other code on the page to execute if the link is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim IsValid as Boolean = YourScriptThatCheckForValidLink()
If Not IsValid Then
    Response.Write("This link has expired.")
    HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what the issue was, but I couldn't find HttpApplication anywhere, IIS always said it didn't recognize it.

ended up with

```
    response.write ("<HTML><head></head><body>This Link has expired</body></HTML>")
    response.end()
```